# how to get the feed activities of an user?

Tags: spotify-app

I am trying to get the activity feeds of a user for 2 days. After trying all sorts of things I got to the result, that I am getting an empty array.

Do I have to get some kind of authorization? But if so it should return something if I fetch my own feed. I used this code:

var snap = aFeed.activities.snapshot(0, 50);
        console.log(snap);

and I am getting a Promise with empty arrays.

Comment: Not sure if its related, but yesterday on IRC, another user reported issues loading the current user (or any user for that matter) and I was able to repro the problem.

Comment: I suspect it could be because I am using the Linux Preview Desktop Client.

Answer (score 0):

Guess there's no more need to answer this question because is not taking app submissions any more.

http://devnews.spotify.com/2014/03/24/closure-of-spotify-apps-submissions/